# assign object to type that is unknown until runtime

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method that will take in an array and return another array of the same type, double the size and with the same contents.  However I need a way of assigning the array type to something that will not be known until runtime. example:

```
public object[] doubleArray(object[] array) {
---[] arrayCopy = new ---[array.length*2];
//copy content
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        arrayCopy[i] = array[i];
}
return arrayCopy;
}
```

The array passed in will not be known until runtime.
Thanks any help will be greatly appreciated

PS I realise that managing of array sizes can be done with ArrayLists etc but for this purposes it would be great to keep things to arrays.

Comment: How is the type determined at runtime?

Comment: List.toarray implementation could be a hint

Comment: Why can't you just use Object[] as the type?

Comment: Just use `ArrayList`s. I doubt you have much to gain here. I'm guessing the reflection code to do this correctly is going to offset any performance gains you can hope to achieve by avoiding array copies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do for a generic array is

```
public static <A> A doubleArray(A array) {
    int length = Array.getLength(array);
    Class<?> componentType = array.getClass().getComponentType();
    A copy = (A) Array.newInstance(componentType, length * 2);
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, copy, 0, length);
    return copy;
}
```

Note: this will work for all arrays including primitive arrays.

```
int[] ints = doubleArray(new int[4]);
String[] strings = doubleArray("a,b,c,d,e,f".split(","));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks like a nice solution.  I'm a java beginner so I was wondering if you could explain some parts of the code?  As in what does the <A> and the class<> mean?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Arrays.copyOf(T[] original, int newLength)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29) if you are working with Java 1.6 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a variant to Peter Lawrey's answer, you can do this as long is you know that you're dealing with an array of some reference type (as opposed to some of the primitive numeric types like `byte[]`):

```
public static Object[] doubleArray(Object[] array) {
    Object[] ret = (Object[])Array.newInstance(src.getClass().getComponentType(), src.length * 2);
    System.arraycopy(src, 0, ret, 0, src.length);
    return(ret);
}
```

It has the advantage of not containing any unchecked generic casts, so it doesn't generate any warnings.